# Limit response size with go-swagger openAPI

Tags: go, swagger, openapi

I'm using go-swagger openAPI for generating a REST client.

Now I would like to limit the response size to a maximum of e.g. 1MB. In Go this would mean using a LimitReader when consuming the body of the response.

Is there a way to limit the response size with go-swagger openAPI as well?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to implement a custom [`runtime.Consumer`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/go-openapi/runtime#Consumer), then use it when implementing your client.

Your generated client code will have exported [variadic functions](https://gobyexample.com/variadic-functions) that allow for an arbitrary number of client options to be passed in. These client options will be a Go type (`ClientOption`) that is a function that accepts a [`*runtime.ClientOperation`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/go-openapi/runtime#ClientOperation).

Create a `ClientOption` function that will assign its argument's `Reader` field to a custom [`runtime.ClientResponseReader`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/go-openapi/runtime#ClientResponseReader) interface implementation. This custom implementation should wrap the old one, but use your desired consumer.

### Custom `runtime.Consumer`

```golang
type customLimitConsumer struct {
    limit int64
}

func (c customLimitConsumer) Consume(reader io.Reader, i interface{}) error {

    // Read all the data, up to the limit.
    data, err := ioutil.ReadAll(io.LimitReader(reader, c.limit))
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    // TODO Unmarshal data into i.

    return nil
}
```

### Custom `runtime.ClientResponseReader` wrapper.

```golang
type myClientResponseReader struct {
    consumer                runtime.Consumer
    oldClientResponseReader runtime.ClientResponseReader
}

func (m myClientResponseReader) ReadResponse(response runtime.ClientResponse, _ runtime.Consumer) (interface{}, error) {
    return m.oldClientResponseReader.ReadResponse(response, m.consumer)
}
```

### Custom `ClientOption` function to pass as an argument to generated variadic function

```golang
var myClientOption api.ClientOption
myClientOption = func(operation *runtime.ClientOperation) {
    oldReader := operation.Reader
    operation.Reader = myClientResponseReader{
        consumer: customLimitConsumer{
            limit: 1000000,
        },
        oldClientResponseReader: oldReader,
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't have a variadic function to pass the ClientOption to. My generated client has the following interfaces: func New(runtime.ClientTransport, strfmt.Registry) *Client; func NewHTTPClientWithConfig( strfmt.Registry,  *TransportConfig) *Client; func NewHTTPClient(strfmt.Registry) *Client; Where do I have to set the ClientOption?

Comment: It sounds like you're using the wrong Go package, the top level package probably called `client`. You'll need to access a package that's a level deeper. For example, if your code generator made a directory called `client`, list the contents of that directory and look for another directory containing a Go package. Maybe there's a directory called `api` in there. It's relative path would be `client/api` You'll access that as a Go package, then perform the steps I described in the response.